# How to get JSON Array in a blob storage using dataflow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Dataflow in Data-Factory.
I have an Azure SQL database as a source. Below is the sample:

```
Firstname Lastname Age phone      mobile
Don       Bosco    56  34578970   134643455
Abraham   Lincoln  87  56789065   246643556
```

Below is the dataflow:

```
Source -> Sink (JSON Blob storage)
```

In the sink, I am getting a single file and the output is like:

```
{"Firstname": "Don", "Lastname": Bosco, "Age": 56, "contact": [{"number": "34578970", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "134643455", "type": "mobile"}]}
{"Firstname": "Abraham", "Lastname": Lincoln, "Age": 87, "contact": [{"number": "56789065", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "246643556", "type": "mobile"}]}
```

Instead, I need to get the output as below:

```
[
    {"Firstname": "Don", "Lastname": Bosco, "Age": 56, "contact": [{"number": "34578970", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "134643455", "type": "mobile"}]},
    {"Firstname": "Abraham", "Lastname": Lincoln, "Age": 87, "contact": [{"number": "56789065", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "246643556", "type": "mobile"}]}
]
```

I know how to do this in copy activity but can't find any way to do this with dataflow. I need to do this in dataflow because copy data activity does not support complex types and so array inside json is not supported.
Kindly, help solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to output this as array instead of struct. Use an aggregator with no group by and collect all the rows(collect function) with the syntax -
collect(@(FirstName = FirstName, Lastname = LastName.....)).

Here you will get an array of structures. You can write this to JSON sink.

Comment: I tried and I still need to give column names in the aggregate which comes as a key in the JSON. So if I give column name as "demographics" I get:
{"demographics": [
    {"Firstname": "Don", "Lastname": Bosco, "Age": 56, "contact": [{"number": "34578970", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "134643455", "type": "mobile"}]},
    {"Firstname": "Abraham", "Lastname": Lincoln, "Age": 87, "contact": [{"number": "56789065", "type": "phone"}, {"number": "246643556", "type": "mobile"}]}
]}

Comment: So it doesn't solve my problem. Is there a way to get rid of the key?