# python function with blobTrigger not getting executed

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I have written a program to convert a file JSON in each line to convert into a JSON array.
Refer to the below link to understand what I want to achieve:
[How to get JSON Array in a blob storage using dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66166915/how-to-get-json-array-in-a-blob-storage-using-dataflow)

I have created below files for trigger:

function.json:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "jsonfiletrigger",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "<containername>/in.json",
      "connection": "<Storage account>"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobin",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "<containername>/in.json",
      "connection": "<Storage account>"
    },
    {
      "name": "blobout",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "path": "<containername>/out.json",
      "connection": "<Storage account>"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

host.json:

```
{
  "version": "2.0"
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<Storage account>;AccountKey=<Storage account access key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~3",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<appinsight instrumentation key>",
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "InstrumentationKey=<Instrumentation key>;IngestionEndpoint=https://westeurope-3.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {}
}
```

**init**.py

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import sys
import json
import os

def main(blobin: func.InputStream, blobout: func.Out[bytes], context: func.Context):
    logging.info('env variables :: %s' % dict(os.environ))

    jsonarr = []

    try:
        with open(blobin, 'rt') as fin:
            for line in fin.readlines():
                jsonobj = json.loads(line.strip())
                jsonarr.append(jsonobj)
    except OSError as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: Unable to read input as file. {e}')
        sys.exit(254)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: {e}')
        sys.exit(255)
 
    try:
        with open(blobout, 'wt') as fout:
            json.dump(jsonarr, indent=4, fp=fout)
    except OSError as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: Unable to write output. {e}')
        sys.exit(254)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'EXCEPTION: {e}')
        sys.exit(255)
```

I ran the below command to publish:

```
func azure functionapp publish jsonlisttoarray --publish-local-settings
```

I see files are in the functionapp. But not sure why the function doesn't get triggered.

Please help resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be caused by the connection string of storage account hadn't been uploaded to azure portal when you do deployment.

We can see the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file) shows us values in **ConnectionStrings** will not be published to azure when you run the command `func azure functionapp publish jsonlisttoarray --publish-local-settings`.

[image]

I test it in my side, the values under `ConnectionStrings` field in `local.settings.json` wasn't published to function application settings on portal when I do deployment. And it will lead to the function can't be triggered.

To solve this problem, you need to go to your function app on azure portal first. Then click "Configuration" --> under "Application settings" tab --> click "New application setting" to add a variable with the name and value same with it in your `local.settings.json` under `ConnectionStrings` field.

================================**Update**================================

It seems you there is a mistake of `connection` field in your `function.json`. First, you should add a variable in `local.settings.json` with the value of the storage connection string like below:
[image]

Then set the value of `connection` field with the name of connection string(in `local.settings.json`) in `function.json`:
[image]

Then deploy the function to azure again with the command `func azure functionapp publish jsonlisttoarray --publish-local-settings`.

**Note**: if you do not add `--publish-local-settings` in your publish command, it will not upload the value in `local.settings.json` to your function app when you do deployment.

Comment: In the local.settings.json I have not filled ConnectionStrings. Where can I find the required values?

Comment: @VizeetSrivastava May I know the value of `connection` in your `function.json` ? Just the name of your storage account like `huryStorageAccount` ? Or the connection string of your storage ?

Comment: @VizeetSrivastava It seems the `connection` field in your `function.json` is incorrect. Please refer to the update of my answer.

Comment: Hi @VizeetSrivastava May I know if your problem was solved ? If still have problem, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks Hury. Today I'll try to deploy the code to azure functions based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I found that problem was with the directory structure. I was have having all the files in the same directory. I needed to have function.json and **init**.py or any other sources under  directory.
A function-app can have multiple functions each function shares the same settings,  requirements.txt, and host.json.
The directory structure looks like below:

```
$ ls -Ra
.:
.  ..  BlobTrigger  extensions.csproj  host.json  local.settings.json  proxies.json  .python_packages  requirements.txt

./BlobTrigger:
.  ..  function.json  __init__.py

./.python_packages:
.  ..
```